# Carousels not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have launched a website but I can't figure out why the carousels don't load up correctly each time the site is visited and it sometimes requires reloading it multiple times - The images have all been downsized for web and I don't know how to fix it,

http://alexburger.co/Graphic.html

https://codepen.io/glittergirl/pen/pZwaaQ

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('.main-carousel').flickity({
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    imagesLoaded: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    bgLazyLoad: 1
    // adaptiveHeight: true
  });

  $('.main-carousel2').flickity({
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    imagesLoaded: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    bgLazyLoad: 1
    // adaptiveHeight: true
  });
});
```

Comment: OMG, your page Graphic.html downloads like 50mb+ of png... Likely unrelated to your problem, but maybe you should resize a bit your pictures... The loading duration will be awful.

Comment: Yeah just checked it out and the image sizes are huge. Scale them down they are twice the width of a normal view port.

Comment: That must be the problem, I did process them all through ImageAlpha and ImageOptim. How would you recommend resizing? photoshop?

Comment: Any image editor should work fine try to get the image sizes to be 1:1 scale when they are on a full size screen any bigger would be a waste.